# Operations in geolocation onSuccess callback

Tags: javascript, cordova, callback

I'm writting an application in Phonegap and I've came across a problem. I'm using watchPosition method from navigator.geolocation . In the onSuccess callback I have to do many operations which are modifying some global values. The problem is, that sometimes (often) one callback is fired before the previos one has finished it's work. It leads to significant data inconsistency. I've tried to modify "maximumAge" option (frequency is no longer suported in phonegap) but it didnt change anything - onSuccess callback is still invoked every second. What should I do to solve this problem? Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried skiping some messages?

```
if(!running)
{ 
 running=true;
..code here...
 running=false
}
```